# DC-DC buck converter inductor current

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, resistive-load

Draw a simple dc to dc buck converter fed with dc voltage of constant magnitude (= E). The
converter supplies a resistive load (=R). Draw the shape of voltage waveform across the
freewheeling diode. Assuming continuous load current, derive the relation between input
voltage (E) and average magnitude of load voltages for switch duty ratio = D.

While deriving
the relation between input and output voltages why continuous current through buck
circuit’s inductor is assumed?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Bhavya. Can you add a schematic for the buck converter you are discussing? Tip: when you use the editor toolbar **CircuitLab** button to draw your schematic you can use the **Save and Insert** button to insert a PNG of the schematic into the post along with an edit link. There's no need for a CircuitLab account. No screengrab. No grid. It alsow means that others can copy and paste your schematic for further editing.

Comment: Please add the schematic. This detail is important.

Comment: Bhavya Puri - Hi, (a) It *seems* that first paragraph is a copy of your assignment. Is that true? As stated in [this site rule](/help/referencing), you should [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) copied material, to make it clear which part is copied. (b) If that paragraph is copied, you should include an appropriate reference as explained in that site rule. If it is an exercise from your college's private material, then perhaps you can't provide a link to the source, but should still give a best-efforts citation explaining the origin. (c) Please add the missing schematic.

Answer (score 2):

> While deriving the relation between input and output voltages why continuous current through buck circuit’s inductor is assumed?

It looks simpler for both the lecturer and the student to start with steady-state CCM as the derivation is easy (with some assumptions, of course) and the the relation becomes load-independent. As you might already know, for CCM operation, the input-output relation depends on only the duty-cycle, D. It's also easier for the students (as far as I can tell) to understand the average and the ripple currents over CCM.

But if you work out steady-state DCM you'll notice that the derivation of input-output relation becomes really complex and also the result becomes load-dependent.